# PysimpleGui - confusion about size=(1, 1) and image coloring in Chess example

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am going through the chess example from PysimpleGui examples and I am confused about this part:

```
def render_square(image, key, location):
    if (location[0] + location[1]) % 2:
        color =  '#B58863'
    else:
        color = '#F0D9B5'
    return sg.RButton('', image_filename=image, size=(1, 1), button_color=("white", color), pad=(0, 0), key=key)
```

Here the size (1,1) represents the image_size it seems?
However if I change the size, I don't see any changes. I assumed the tiles
would get bigger?

As for coloring of the images, it seems the "blank" tiles are originally black, so they are getting turned to white, and then the board "color"(brown) is being applied to them..

However, the chess pieces are retaining their colors (white or black),
despite having this function applied to them as well. Their background are changing but the pieces itself aren't changing. What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Look through the docs. The sizes tend to be characters in PySimpleGUI.  In this case, the button size doesn't matter because an image is being placed on it.  In the docs you'll find info on sizing of images on buttons - https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#button-element.  You may also want to ask these kinds of questions on the project's GitHub site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the color of the button will not change the color of the image on the button.  It change the color of the button.  Buttons have 2 colors, the background and the text.

If you want to change the image color, then you'll need something like PIL to do that.

You can change the size of the image but not the "color" using the Button Element.  Again, the docs are key in understanding how this is done. It's not a pixel specification you can give.  A "Subsample" is used which will make the image 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5,..., the size it originally was.